# Search 'Checked' CheckBox in Another Excel File using vba macro

Tags: excel, checkbox, excel-2010, visual-studio-macros, vba

My problem I think is quite simple, but since I am new to this excel vba macro, it is quite tricky.
To put it simply, I have two excel file.One with "Refresh" Button. 
Another excel file with several CheckBoxs, with some words and number in different cell same row. 
So, when I press "Refresh", I only need info only on the 'ticked' Checkbox. 
And the info will change when I 'untick' the CheckBox, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

I put in the sample 1 button (WorkSheet1) and 3 CheckBox (WorkSheet2).
In the code of Button of Worksheet(1) you write:

```
With Workbooks("Book2")
    Range("A1").Value = .Sheets("Sheet1").checkbox1.Value
    Range("A2").Value = .Sheets("Sheet1").checkbox2.Value
    Range("A3").Value = .Sheets("Sheet1").checkbox3.Value
End With
```

This code capture the state of Workbooks(2)... 
Modify this code you can capture the data you want.
If you want, in every code of chackbox of Worksheet(2) this code:

```
With Workbooks("Book1")
    .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = CheckBox1.Value
End With
```

This code write True or False for every CheckBox...

Comment: Forgot to say Thank You. You really help a lot. @user3514930

Comment: Excel / VBA it's a interesting GAME ;-))